# Dictionary in Python which keeps the last x accessed keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a dictionary in python which will only keep the most recently accessed keys. Specifically, I am caching relatively large blobs of data in a dictionary, and I am looking for a way of preventing the dictionary from ballooning in size, and to drop to the variables which were only accessed a long time ago [i.e. to only keep the say the 1000 most recently accessed keys - and when a new key gets added, to drop the key that was accessed the longest ago].

I suspect this is not part of the standard dictionary class, but am hoping there is something analogous.

Comment: You can add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question and make it more clear.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you want a Least Recently Used (LRU) cache.
Here's a Python implementation already: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lru-dict/

Here's another one: https://www.kunxi.org/blog/2014/05/lru-cache-in-python/

Comment: Incredibly useful utility when writing your own in memory cache vs. using memcache or something similar (you'd be surprised how often this sadly happens).

Comment: Ironically the first one you posted *isn't* a python implementation. It's written in C, so it won't run on things like pypy.